# meaning of top level private class in scala

Tags: scala

Say in a scala file I define a class like

```
private class Test{}
```

what does the private here mean? In java you can't have a top level private class, which obviously makes sense. But private is syntactically valid in scala, hope someone can shed some light upon it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could specify package name for `private` modifier to allow access to this class only from specified package. By default (without package specified) it is visible only for other members in the enclosing package.

```
$ cat > test.scala <<EOF
package myPackage {
  private[myPackage] class Test
  private object A extends Test
}

package otherPackage {
  object B extends myPackage.Test
}
EOF

$ scalac test.scala 
test.scala:7: error: class Test in package myPackage cannot be accessed in package myPackage
  object B extends myPackage.Test
                             ^
one error found
```

For instance you can access `private` class from its companion object like this:

```
trait ITest
private class Test extends ITest
object Test {
  def apply(): ITest = new Test
}

Test()
// ITest = Test@59e2abc3
```

Further clarification on examples:

```
package myPackage {
  private class Test
  private object A extends Test
  object B extends myPackage.Test //Compile error: private class Test escapes its defining scope as part of type myPackage.Test
  private object C extends myPackage.Test // works since C is also private

  object Test {
     def apply() = new Test //error: private class Test escapes its defining scope as part of type myPackage.Test
   } 
   object Test2 {
      def apply(): ITest = new Test //works as ITest is public 
    }
}
```

As long as instances of a private class do not escape the enclosing package scope it can be used within the package hierarchy. Companion objects accessing private classes has to be in same package hierarchy as well. With `private[P]` - `p` can be any package name that exists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it safe to say if a class is declared private, it is only accessible from the same package? So what package my Test class is in?

Comment: @som-snytt: Thank you,fixed. Also I couldn't find difference between `private` and `private[enclosingPackage]` in the SLS. Did I miss something, or is [this code](http://pastebin.com/pmQE6PL7) reproduces a bug in compiler?

Comment: @som-snytt: see [detailed example](http://pastebin.com/nyi7s97s). In case of `private[myPackage]` I can access to `A.i` (inherited from `private[myPackage] class`) - isn't is a bug? And if it's not a bug the behavior of `private class` is completely different: I can't even compile public object that extends private class, and this makes sense.

Comment: Long ago: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/UyWS5X9CH-g  I'll follow up when I've re-assimilated it.

Comment: Short answer: there is a bug parade. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2568 and many related, up to https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8155 not to mention plain old privates https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8143

Comment: Forgot to add link to the thread that precedes the last one; it goes in a circle, with one explanation about why something doesn't compile interrupted with, Never mind, paulp just told me it does compile. http://grokbase.com/t/gg/scala-user/129my6ga7t/protected-inner-class-escapes-its-defining-scope